# A kind of integration testing in ASP.NET Core, with EF and AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, xunit

I'm trying to test the path from my ASP.NET Core Controller to the DB, through repository which includes the usage of AutoMapper.

Here's my repository:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using DS.DTO.MasterData;
using DS.Utilities.DSExceptions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Omu.ValueInjecter;

namespace DS.MasterData.Repositories
{
    public class PersonFactRepository : IPersonFactRepository
    {
        private readonly Database.MasterDataContext dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger<PersonFactRepository> logger;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        public PersonFactRepository(ILogger<PersonFactRepository> logger, Database.MasterDataContext dbcontext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbcontext;
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public PatientDto CreatePatient(CreatePatientDto inModel)
        {
            var dbPersonDim = mapper.Map<CreatePatientDto, Database.PersonDim>(inModel);
            var dbAddressDim = mapper.Map<CreatePatientDto, Database.AddressDim>(inModel);
            var dbPhoneDim = mapper.Map<CreatePatientDto, Database.PhoneDim>(inModel);

            var dbPersonFact = new Database.PersonFact { FactId = Guid.NewGuid() };

            dbPersonDim.PersonFact = dbPersonFact;
            dbAddressDim.PersonFact = dbPersonFact;
            dbPhoneDim.PersonFact = dbPersonFact;

            dbPersonDim.InitDates();
            dbAddressDim.InitDates();
            dbPhoneDim.InitDates();

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var returnVal = new PatientDto();
            returnVal.InjectFrom(dbPersonDim)
                     .InjectFrom(dbAddressDim)
                     .InjectFrom(dbPhoneDim);

            return returnVal;
        }
    }
}
```

My AutoMapper configuration:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<CreatePatientDto, Database.PersonDim>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CreatePatientDto, Database.AddressDim>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CreatePatientDto, Database.PhoneDim>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

My problem is how do I get my Mapper configuration into my fakeMapper?

```
var inMemDB = Fakes.FakeDB.DB;
var loggerCntl = Substitute.For<ILogger<Controllers.PatientController>>();
var loggerPersonFactRepo = Substitute.For<ILogger<Repositories.PersonFactRepository>>();

AutoMapper.IMapper fakeMapper = ????

var personRepo = new PersonFactRepository(loggerPersonFactRepo, inMemDB, fakeMapper);
```

It's on purpose that I'm going for a integration test, as I want my test to be able to post data to the controller and test if the right data ends up in the right tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a mapper provider

   ```
   public class MapperProvider
   {
       public MapperProvider() { 

       }
       public MapperConfiguration GetMapperConfig()
       {
           var mce = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
           mce.AddProfile<AutoMapperConfig>();
           var mc = new MapperConfiguration(mce);
           return mc;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register the mapping config

   ```
   AutoMapper.IMapper fakeMapper = new Mapper(new 
       MapperProvider().GetMapperConfig());
   ```